# Google datastore and materialized paths

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gae-datastore

Folks from MongoDB have documented a very nice approach of using a data model for tree-like structures: they call it *[Materialized Paths](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/)*.

Consider following:

[image: Hierarchy]

If I populate this hierarchy using following code:

```js
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", path: null } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", path: ",Books," } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", path: ",Books,Programming," } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", path: ",Books,Programming," } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", path: ",Books,Programming,Databases," } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "dbm", path: ",Books,Programming,Databases," } )
```

I can easily retrieve, for example, all descendants of *Programming*:

```js
db.categories.find( { path: /,Programming,/ } )
```

Now I'm considering of moving this database into [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/), but I'm concerned about how painful would be to perform queries for such filtering? Can someone provide an example?

If it's relevant, backend is written in Go.